# I need a SQL query/SSIS transform in SSIS that checks date?

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

So I'm using a SCD transform in SSIS and when it sets a begin date by default it's the current date which is fine. But what I want to do with my initial load is to set all new records as 2008-01-01 and then anything after that's new is going to be the current date.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your data flow task use a Execute SQL Task and run a query similar to this to see if your destination table is empty(initial load)-
IF (SELECT count(1) FROM [Table].[Destination])>0
BEGIN
 SELECT 0 as TableEmpty
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 SELECT 1 as TableEmpty
END

Store the result of the query in a Boolean variable - isTableEmpty.

Now in your data flow task after the SCD and before the insert destination for New Output use a derived column task - DerivedBeginDate with the expression having the following logic.
(isTableEmpty)?(DT_DBDATE)"2008-01-01":BeginDateFromSCD

Map the DerivedBeginDate to the column in the Insert Destination.

Hope this helps. Good Luck.